# гифка в телеграм бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть бот. Юзер нажимает кнопку, бот делает запрос в [БД](http://animashki.kak2z.org/category.php?cat=5&pn=0) и достает нужную информацию. И есть гифка ([пример](http://animashki.kak2z.org/pic/5/dogs-1030.gif)).

Как сделать так, чтобы пока юзер ждет ответа, показывалась гифка? Если не затруднит, показать кодом на практике.

Вот мой код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    button_push = callback_query
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, config.switch_button.get(button_push))
    print(button_push.data)
    push = button_push.data
    button_request = config.switch_button.get(push)
    print(button_request)
    con = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', password='', database='testop')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(button_request)
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        print(rows)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гиф можно отправить 3 способами:

Используя file_id: gif = 'CgACAgEAAxkBAAEBICR...'

Используя прямую ссылку: gif = 'http://animashki.kak2z.org/pic/5/dogs-1030.gif'

Или загрузить напрямую: gif = open('gif.gif', 'rb')

```
wait = await bot.send_animation(chat_id, gif, caption = 'Loading...')
# Do something
await bot.delete_message(chat_id, wait.message_id)
```